# how do I get my Ajax to return a function and prevent my document from downloading onclick

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

I have been trying to figure this out for hours. 
I have the following document path on and anchor tag

```
<a href="@link.DocumentPath" onclick="return checkAuth(@link.Id, @PasswordProtected)">@link.Title</a>
```

I do not want to process the href if the "checkAuth" function returns a false. 
Here is the "checkAuth" code.

```
var checkAuth = function(id, PasswordProtected) {
                    var result = null;
                    var hostname = location.hostname;
                    var host = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hostroot"]';
                    if (hostname == "localhost")
                        host = "";
                    if (PasswordProtected == "1"){
                        var pass = prompt("This document is password protected", "");

                        var response = $.ajax({

                            type: "GET",
                            url: host + "/Communities/DeCryptPwd/",

                            data: {"id": id, "password": pass},
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert(data);
                                if (data == "True")
                                    result = true;
                                if (data == "False")
                                    result = false;

                            },
                            error: function (errorData) { alert(errorData); }
                        });
}
```

I just don't know how to stop the processing of the document on the href and return a true ... continue process, or false -- stop processing.

Just in case you need it, here is the "sever side" code called by the .ajax

```
public bool DeCryptPwd(int id, string password) {
    var encrypted = db.CommunityDocs.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => x.Password).SingleOrDefault();

    /* Extract the bytes */
    byte[] hashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
    /* Get the salt */
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, salt, 0, 16);
    /* Compute the hash on the password the user entered */
    var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 10000);
    byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(20);
    /* Compare the results */
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        if (hashBytes[i + 16] != hash[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: a `return false` at the end of your function would help a lot. You cannot however return the result from an async function. So you need to change the location in the success part

Comment: well, I understand the return false, and that does work. I am not certain I understand the changing the location in the success part

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return the result from an async function from the function that contains it. So you need to change the location in the success part and return true if not protected.

However the code will currently allow them to right-click and open in new window regardless

```js
function checkAuth = function(theLink) {
  var id = theLink.id,
      protected = theLink.getAttribute("pass") == "1",
      href = theLink.href,
      result = null,
      hostname = location.hostname,
      host = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hostroot"]';
  if (hostname == "localhost")
    host = "";
  if (protected) {
    var pass = prompt("This document is password protected", "");

    var response = $.ajax({

      type: "GET",
      url: host + "/Communities/DeCryptPwd/",

      data: {
        "id": id,
        "password": pass
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        if (data == "True") {
          location = href;
        }
      },
      error: function(errorData) {
        alert(errorData);
      }
    });
    return !protected; // return false if protected
  }
```

```html
<a href="@link.DocumentPath" onclick="return checkAuth(this)" id="@link.Id" data-pass="@PasswordProtected">@link.Title</a>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but unfortunately, this did not work. The first line function checkAuth = function(link) { ...I am getting an error "use of a keywork as an identifier is invalid.

Comment: So rename link var to myLink

Comment: okay, I think I am making some progress, but the "protected = link.getAttribute ... I changed the "link" to "theLink" ... but it is still returning a false, when I know it is true. I think if I can get that fixed, this may work

Comment: got it to work, I can't tell you how happy this makes me.

Comment: well, i spoke too soon, I tried another document without a password protection and it is showing as a "1" as well. so I am troubleshooting that

Comment: nevermind ... I had a flaw in my logic that encrypts and flags the document link as password protected. I corrected it and all works. Thank you again